# backbone; load same view when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've created an onclick event that generates a view. After navigating to a different page, and going back, the generated view is no longer there.

Is there any way to load the onclick when page loads by going through a link or browser back button?

Comment: Save the search criteria in `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` and if the users goes back to the that view create the table again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Backbone router, 
so when it gets the url it will initialize the view

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    "help":                 "help",    // #help
    "search/:query":        "search",  // #search/kiwis
    "search/:query/p:page": "search"   // #search/kiwis/p7
  },

  help: function() {
    new MyView;
  },

  search: function(query, page) {
    new MySearchView({foo: "bar" });
  }

});
```

and don't forget to start history with Backbone.history.start() , that way it will manage back button and push state

regards